# Installation of different versions of Mule ESB in the same server

Tags: installation, esb, mule

PROBLEM - Can different versions of Mule be deployed (say Mule 2.0 and 2.2.0) in the same server?

They will be used for different applications.

1. Will there be any conflict because of it?
2. Should any pre-requisites be taken care before doing that way
3. Do you foresee any potential risks in this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely do this. Just make sure to ensure you are not using the same ports for any of your service and have each application set their own MULE_HOME.